# Formula suggestion for a scoring system, weighted solution

Tags: probability

I'm trying to validate a series of words that are provided by users. I'm trying to come up with a scoring system that will determine the likelihood that the series of words are indeed valid words.

Assume the following input:

```
xxx yyy zzz
```

The first thing I do is check each word individually against a database of words that I have. So, let's say that `xxx` was in the database, so we are 100% sure it's a valid word. Then let's say that `yyy` doesn't exist in the database, but a possible variation of its spelling exist (say `yyyy`). We don't give `yyy` a score of 100%, but maybe something lower (let's say 90%). Then `zzz` just doesn't exist at all in the database. So, `zzz` gets a score of 0%.

So we have something like this:

```
xxx = 100%
yyy = 90%
zzz = 0%
```

Assume further that the users are either going to either:

1. Provide a list of all valid words (most likely)
2. Provide a list of all invalid words (likely)
3. Provide a list of a mix of valid and invalid words (not likely)

As a whole, what is a good scoring system to determine a confidence score that `xxx yyy zzz` is a series of valid words? I'm not looking for anything too complex, but getting the average of the scores doesn't seem right. If some words in the list of words are valid, I think it increases the likelihood that the word not found in the database is an actual word also (it's just a limitation of the database that it doesn't contain that particular word).

NOTE: The input will generally be a minimum of 2 words (and mostly 2 words), but can be 3, 4, 5 (and maybe even more in some rare cases).

**EXAMPLE 1:**

Say the following scores:

```
xxx = 100%
yyy = 100%
zzz = 0%
```

The average is 66.66%. But since already two words in the list exist in the database, the chances are that `zzz` is also a real word. Scoring this series of words as just 66.66% seems low.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a list of valid/invalid entries to use as a training set?  If so, that would help a lot to see how useful your intuition is about invalid words occurring together, and also to find a good weighted combination.  Also, you may want to consider building a [gibberish detector](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6298193/286449), like I did in that answer, that scores words as 'English-like' or not based on their sequence of characters.

Comment: I have a list of valid entries. That's the dictionary of words in the database, which I use to first check if the word is valid or not. Words that are not in the database aren't necessarily invalid. That's why I want to assign an overall score to the series of words that I am evaluating. Gibberish detector won't work for me as I am dealing with multi-lingual string of words. I just want to be able to use previous successful matches to influence the overall score. Averaging is not right.

Comment: You can build a multi-lingual gibberish detector, and you can even do so by using your database of valid words to train it.  There are generalizations of averages that give more weight to higher weighted items (so any good individual word score can count for a lot), like root mean square that you might want to play with.

Comment: Gibberish detector is not the preferred approach, as mentioned. It'll be hard for me to train it as I don't have a good sampling to use. I need to estimate the odds that a word that doesn't exist in the DB is valid or not based on the other words that do exist.